# How to destruct messages after calling endSimulation() in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I have a sensor network where nodes exchange messages and calculate some parameters on which we decide if a clone has been inserted into the network or not. If it is the case, I call the `endSimulation()` instruction in order to stop the simulation. But I noticed that some messages continue to be exchanged after the instruction `endsimulation()` and I got the message:

> undisposed object: (omnetpp::cMessage) Drones.clone.app.event2 -- check module destructor"

Although I have a `finish()` method where I `cancelAndDelete(event2)`. I want to know how to delete event after calling `endSimulation()`.

Comment: Do you call `endSimulation()` in your code? Usually there is no need to call this method - it is enough to control simulation using `sim-time-limit` option.

Comment: I agree, but if I set the sim-time-limit to x time and I detect the attack at y time and y < x, an attack is detected but the simulation continue and this is not what I want.

Comment: OK, I see your point. According to your message - how many instances of event2 do you create? Does event2 variable hold always the same massage?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jerzy, I tested the way you suggest (set the sim-time-limit) and I still got the same message so it wasn't the endSimulation() instruction the source of the problem. I solved the problem by creating a single instance of the event2, I noticed that I was creating new one each time.